# Parsing an xs:duration datatype into a Python datetime.timedelta object?

Tags: python, datetime, xsd, duration, timedelta

As per the title, I'm trying to parse an XML file containing an [`xs:duration`](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp#duration) data type. I'd like to convert that into a Python [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object, which I can then use in further calculations.

Is there any built-in way of doing this, similar to the [`strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) function? If not, what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seeing as I already have a working example of what I asked in the question, I'll post it here for completeness. If any better answers come up I'll accept.

```
period = '-P14D'
regex  = re.compile('(?P<sign>-?)P(?:(?P<years>\d+)Y)?(?:(?P<months>\d+)M)?(?:(?P<days>\d+)D)?(?:T(?:(?P<hours>\d+)H)?(?:(?P<minutes>\d+)M)?(?:(?P<seconds>\d+)S)?)?')

# Fetch the match groups with default value of 0 (not None)
duration = regex.match(period).groupdict(0)

# Create the timedelta object from extracted groups
delta = timedelta(days=int(duration['days']) + (int(duration['months']) * 30) + (int(duration['years']) * 365),
                  hours=int(duration['hours']),
                  minutes=int(duration['minutes']),
                  seconds=int(duration['seconds']))

if duration['sign'] == "-":
    delta *= -1
```

This works, but won't handle the month lengths or leap years correctly. For my purposes this isn't an issue, but it is worth keeping in mind.

Comment: This worked great for me until my buddy added milliseconds to his values.  Can anybody update this regex to handle values such as 'P0Y0M0DT1H20M39.123S'?  Thanks!

Comment: `(?P<sign>-?)P(?:(?P<years>\d+)Y)?(?:(?P<months>\d+)M)?(?:(?P<days>\d+)D)?(?:T(?:(?P<hours>\d+)H)?(?:(?P<minutes>\d+)M)?(?:(?P<seconds>\d+[.]?\d*)S)?)?` if you need decimals on the seconds

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but for future reference: You can use `isodate.parse_duration()` for this. It returns a class that is compatible with `timedelta`.

See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isodate

Comment: ```isodate.parse_duration('P0Y0M0DT1H20M39.123S')``` turns into ```datetime.timedelta(0, 4839, 123000)```