# Validate a xs:duration using a regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, xsd, duration

I'm trying to validate a xs:duration and then convert it to seconds. At this time, this is what i have:

```
/P^([-])?(([\d.]*)Y)?(([\d.]*)M)?(([\d.]*)D)?T?(([\d.]*)H)?(([\d.]*)M)?(([\d.]*)S)?/
```

However, is not rejecting these invalid values (taken from [here](http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_duration.html)):

- `P-20M`  the minus sign must appear first
- `P20MT`  no time items are    present, so "T" must not be present
- `P1YM5D` no value is specified for    months, so "M" must not be
  present

What am I missing?

I've found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764269/parsing-an-xsduration-datatype-into-a-python-datetime-timedelta-object), but that regex only works in Python.

Comment: Are you going to use it in XSD `pattern`?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not very sure what you are asking. I'm receiving the duration of video files from a XML and I'd like to validate and transform them to seconds. Then I will use it in my Javascript code to do some calculations, not using any particular pattern.

Comment: Are you asking to modify the pattern? How is it used? Where? Show the code where you are using the pattern.

Comment: Also, the pattern is incorrect, it contains `^` as the second char. If I remove it, `-P60D` is not matched, though it is said it should be. Please provide the list of strings that should match and those that should not in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing several points, which are easily addressed by looking at the descriptions of the failure cases. The following regular expression works for all the cases (and failure cases), see [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/rTg4Do/1)

```
^(-?)P(?=.)((\d+)Y)?((\d+)M)?((\d+)D)?(T(?=.)((\d+)H)?((\d+)M)?(\d*(\.\d+)?S)?)?$
```

First of all, look at `P15.5Y   only the seconds can be expressed as a decimal`. You use `[\d.]*` everywhere, which allows one or more digit or dots everywhere. But only the seconds are allowed to have a single dot, and that dot needs to be followed by a digit. So, change the seconds to `(\d*(\.\d+)?S)` and all the others to `(\d+Y)` (and so on).

Also, the string needs to start with an optional `-`, and then the `P`, so use that:

```
^-?P
```

Then, there must be something after the `P`, just use a lookahead assertion for that:

```
(?=.)
```

Then, there come `Y`, `M` and `D`, as discussed already.

If there is a time component, there must come a `T` now, so make sure we have a `T` if anything else comes:

```
(T(?=.))
```

... and only if we had a `T`, we are allowed to have `H`, `M` or `S`:

```
(T(?=.)(\d+H)?(\d+M)?(\d*(\.\d+)?S)?)
```

The lookahead assertion ensures that we will find something, and the rest captures the HMS part.

Comment: Awesome answer. Works like a champ.

Comment: Where did you get this regex from did you develop it your self and is it released under any license?